# How to notify user at specific time in android?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, notifications

I am developing application which display currency exchange rate in MainActivity. So far Rates is being fetched using third party API and AsyncTask. Now what I suppose to do that notification should be generated if exchange rate cross certain limit. So which approach should i follow to keep app run in background and fetch rates in background as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a service start using periodic alarm. [A tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

Comment: Where you get exchange rate cross certain limit value? i mean getting this value from web-service or somewhere else.

Comment: @MD value from webservice.

Comment: Then you need to go to this [link](http://it-ride.blogspot.in/2010/10/android-implementing-notification.html). it'll show how to create services and request Web-service in background.

Comment: @MD this is what exactly, i was looking for. Thanks a lot. It will be great if you can send me few more this tyep of link with similar example...!!